# Waiting for privilege escalation prompt

Tags: ansible, windows

I'm new with Ansible so hope to find answers here.
I'm trying to run some playbook but getting an error:

```
fatal: [10.65.30.117]: FAILED! => {
  "msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "
}
```

Here are the steps which I performed:

1. I installed Ansible 2.6.17 on RHEL 6.8 using root user.
2. I update /etc/ansible/host with new group of IPs (with root user)
3. I created playbook file (with some other user) with the following content:

```
  name: sample_playbook
  hosts: [ansible_clients]
  remote_user: ronenal
  become: true
  tasks:
     - name: create file
       file:
         path: /tmp/ansible.log
         state: touch
         mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r
```

When I execute `ansible-playbook -sample_playbook.yml` I'm getting the above error.

I set `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1` and it looks like it related to sudo command.
The user which I use is not in the sudoers list.

My questions:

1. Is it required to be a privileged user in order to execute Ansible playbook?
2. if no, what am I doing wrong?
3. if yes, is that mean that I need to add this user to the sudoers users list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to be a privileged user (in your local machine) in order to execute Ansible playbook.

When using `become`, Ansible allows you to ‘become’ another user, different from the user that logged into the machine (remote user).

For more details see [Understanding Privilege Escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html)

In your inventory of hosts `/etc/ansible/host` you have specified a group of IPs with root user while you are specifying a `remote_user: ronenal` in your playbook.

So you need to run ansible-playbook with --ask-become-pass or -K.

Comment: Thanks. I added become_user to the playbook file and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Fodil, but I would also recommend using **psexec** for working with windows. Ansible has a command **"win_psexec"** that helps to use escalated privileges without using **Become**.